# Is there any WEP cracking application available for android?

Tags: wi-fi, security, encryption

Is there any WEP cracking application available for android?

If not is WEP cracking technically possible with the API's and hardware available on your average android phone?

This is a purely academic question please leave ethical arguments out of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing available. While it is theoretically possible with the hardware, in practice it would be very difficult to implement and would probably need a custom ROM that supported it.

Even the tools for doing this on a desktop (Aircrack, etc.) generally require specific wireless chipsets and drivers to do wireless packet capture.

EDIT:
There's now a project that got monitor mode working on the Galaxy S2 and the Google Nexus One.
See http://bcmon.blogspot.de/

Comment: So how can I use that tool? Which app do I need to run it? or is it just an addon so you can use aircrack on the console?

Answer (score 15):

The Broadcom bcm4329 chipset in a lot of android phones (Nexus One, Evo, G1) probably many more) supports monitor/promiscuous mode. The driver needs to be modified to allow monitor mode to be enabled.

Here is the source of the current drivers:

[monitor mode flag](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=kernel/msm.git;a=blob;f=drivers/net/wireless/bcm4329/include/wlioctl.h;h=751d5cdaff76485fbcfada2bd149527418e2f6bf;hb=refs/heads/android-msm-2.6.29-nexusone#l539)

[method to that sets the mode](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=kernel/msm.git;a=blob;f=drivers/net/wireless/bcm4329/wl_iw.c;h=cd387b1ae1641ca29809e6ef1acd419c2a0f66fe;hb=refs/heads/android-msm-2.6.29-nexusone#l1062)

In the second link, you can see that monitor mode flag is not even in the switch statement so it's just gets ignored when called.

Someone also got [tcpdump working on a G1](http://junxian-huang.blogspot.com/2009/03/finally-tcpdump-on-gphone-g1-android.html) so it's possible, we jsut need to put in some work to get it functional though.

A few more links about the chipset, drivers, and modifications to them:

- http://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=281.0
- http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=b43
- http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

Answer (score 1):

As Rohan said, you need at least a device with a wireless card that can be set on "monitor" or "promiscuous" mode, so you can sniff the packets sent between the clients and servers of the wireless network.

So, technically it is possible, but at the beginning it would be a very device-specific solution

Comment: Care to explain why promiscuous mode is needed? I understand that having the ability to monitor the traffic sent forth and back between clients who know the WEP key helps to (quickly) acquire data, which can be analysed to find the key (without being noticed). However, why can't we just brute force guess password and try to connect to the wireless AP. If the server replies with a valid DHCP package, the password was correct and we are connected to the network.

Answer (score -4):

technically no. however you can jailbreak it and install a OS on it and it would look just like a normal OS. just a smaller version. once thats done you can install softwares like aircrack exct. and it would capture the packets and then crack them.. now this does take some time.. anywhere from 15 minutes to a few days all depending on their encryptionsetings. but the average wifi shouldnt take more then 30 minutes.. tops. so yes in theory it is "possible" but it all depends on how much work you want to put into it in order to get it. there is no "app" YET.. im not sure if anyone is converting a software like aircrack from an OS to app compatable.. although im sure someone is somewhere.